# NServiceBus - capturing event handled by "child" saga also in "parent" saga

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus, saga, nservicebus-sagas

I have Saga_X that sends command.
As a result of that command number of Saga_Y instances are created.
At some point Saga_Y handles event. I would like that event to be captured also by Saga_X.
Is there any other way?

I tried to use ReplyToOriginator in Saga_Y but it does not work for Events.
The other option I see is passing ParentCorrelationId and using it to republish event. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Events are handled by subscribing to those events. If you wish to handle the event in both sagas, both should declare handling of that event type using `IHandleMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to accomplish, but this should work:

```
public class Saga_X : Saga<Saga_X_Data>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<InitialEvent>,
    IHandleMessages<Reply>
{
    public async Task Handle(InitialEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        await context.Publish(new SecondEvent());
    }

    public Task Handle(Reply message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class Saga_Y : Saga<Saga_Y_Data>, 
    IAmStartedByMessages<SecondEvent>
{
    public async Task Handle(SecondEvent message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        await context.Reply(new Reply());
    }
}
```